# How to write code if not an element exists in selenium [JAVA]

Tags: java, html, selenium, testing

This a login test scenario. **There are two user. They are valid and invalid users.** Pop-up  OK click is working in testing.

<---- **PROBLEM** ----->

If ----> (if not an element exists) ---- print("successfuly login"),

else ----> (if an element exists)   ----- pop-up ok click. Login with other users.

I can't do this no such element case.

ERROR

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"html/body/div/div/div[3]/button[1]"}
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.88)
```

CODE

```
    WebElement temp444 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div/div/div[3]/button[1]"));
    System.out.println(temp444.getSize());
    if(temp.getSize()!=null){

         temp.click(); // ----> It's working!

    }
    else {

    System.out.println("good working"); // ----> It isn't working.

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `findElements`() which returns list of elements and then check the size of the list if more than 0 means button exists and click on that.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("html/body/div/div/div[3]/button[1]"));
        System.out.println(elements.size());
        if(elements.size()>0)
        {

            elements.get(0).click();

        }
        else {

        System.out.println("good working"); 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use driver.findElements instead of driver.findElement

in this case if element not exist temp.getSize() == 0

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use a try catch block instead of if/else block, similar to
   the below code

   try

   {

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div/div/div[3]/button[1]"));
   ```

   }

   catch(NoSuchElementException)

   {

   ```
   Console.WriteLine("Element does not exist!");
   ```

   }
2. Also you can find if an element present like this.

   Boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(By.yourLocator).size() > 0